# Enable networking protocols over usb

Tags: usb, networking, sony-xperia

This is too specific issue I encoutred with the Sony Experia XZ and somehow only this phone have this problem, The story is that I'm trying to connect a DJI Phantome 4 remote controller with this phone, but the phone doesn't even recognize that I've connected something over USB, in the beginning I thought that the  remote controller is defected, but after testing it with a bunch of other Android SF with the same version 7 all of them works perfectly with the DJI RC over USB with debugging mode active, I've posted the problem in the Sony forum and I've got this answer :

> Hi @zerubeus As @nolramlb has said above, I too have had trouble
>   connecting the Dji controller to the XZ. The only information
>   regarding usb connectivity issues was that the XZ does not support the
>   networking protocols over usb that the phantom controllers may or may
>   not use. I have asked Dji which service the controller uses to connect
>   but they did not reply to my query, similarly, I asked Sony mobile
>   support why this may be happening and they found that usb ethernet
>   services are not supported. Whether this is the service dji use, I
>   don't know, and only dji can say for sure if that service is the one
>   they use on Android.

Now my question is how I cant enable networking protocols, is it just a software layer or the hardware is involved here ? If it is a software restriction does a root to the device can solve that problem ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what your question is. Could you edit it down a bit? Maybe even add a tl;dr :)?

Comment: It's simple !! How can I enable networking services over USB that was disabled by Sony in their Xperia XZ smartphone, is there any alternative to enable networking services over USB ?

Comment: No solution to this ? :/

Comment: Try turning on USB Debugging? Try turning on USB tethering?

Comment: Usb already in debugging mode, Sony engineer told me that networking services was literally deleted from the phone, this is why I want to find an alternative solution to enable those services

Comment: Do you get the N sticky notification logo of USB OTG when you plug in your Xperia to the drone remote?

Comment: No notification when I plug the rc, like I'm doing nothing at all

Comment: This is really strange all other smartphones recognise the RC only this phone don't